# does calling alert() clear the browser cache?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

Sometime while developing a web application with javascript which included in iframe, My newly added codes are only not working ( document saved after new edit ) in the browser but after putting the alert in the top of the JS file the flow started working.

in my javascript file

```
 function    setRangePos(src, x, y) {
        setRangeTop(src, y);       
    }


 function    setRangeTop(src, y) {
            setBaseProp(src, "top", y);  // newly added not working 
    }
```

It worked after puts alert in top of file ( especially in chrome ).

Comment: What is the question? You should give some code of what you did.

Comment: _"does calling alert() clear the browser cache?"_ No. Why would it? (If the browser was using an old version of your file from its cache then it wouldn't actually realise you'd added an alert() anyway...)

Comment: Your javascript is probably executing before the DOM is ready, but when you add the alert, it creates a delay that allows the DOM to finish loading before the rest of your javascript executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the browser's cache. Putting an `alert` will only solve timing issues, because they might give time to some asynchronous operations to complete before the rest of the code runs.